# Matrix norm in the objective of an optimization problem

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am stuck with the following optimization problem from research. 
The optimization problem have the following objective function: $\|Q-H\|_\infty$. Here $Q$ is a PSD matrix and $H$ is a symmetric constant matrix.

The objective function looks to be non-linear. Is there any way to linearize  the objective function? Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which norm is that? and over which domain?

Comment: That is the matrix infinity norm, which is the maximum of the sum of the absolute value of rows of a matrix. The optimization is over the set of all PSD matrices.

Comment: Do you really need $\| \cdot \|_\infty$? For the frobenius norm, the problem can be solved using the eigenvalue decomposition of $H$.

Comment: What software are you using to solve this problem? Tools like CVX and YALMIP can accept this matrix norm as-is, automatically transforming it to solvable form.

Comment: I ask again. Do you really need $\|\cdot\|_\infty$? The SDP formulation I come up with looks awefully large.

Comment: Yes, I need $||.||_\infty$ norm.

Comment: You should try CVX, if you don't need to implement it yourself or at least for the prototype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rephrase $\| Q - H \|_\infty$ using additional dummy variables and constraints, and turn the problem into a linear semidefinite program.

Just use following the tricks

1. For $x\in\mathbb R, u, v \ge 0$ with $x = u - v$ it follows $|x| \le u+v$. The equality holds if $u$ or $v$ is zero.
2. Instead of minimize $\max\{x,y\}$, minimize $z$ with $x \le z$ and $y \le z$.

Comment: Thanks. I understood the second trick. But, how do you use the first trick in this problem?

Comment: Consider say $\mathbb R^{2\times 2}$. We have $\| X \|_\infty = \max\{|X_{1,1}| + |X_{1,2}|, |X_{2,1}|+|X_{2,2}|\}$. Now, split $X$ into $U-V$ where the components of $U$ and $V$ are non-negative, and we have $\| X \|_\infty \le \max\{ U_{1,1}+V_{1,1} + U_{1,2}+V_{1,2}, U_{2,1}+V_{2,1} + U_{2,2}+V_{2,2}\}$. Apply trick 2 and you have a linear objective function.

Comment: I was just too lazy to write the formulae with sum sign and indices. It works for any (finite ;) dimensions ... and could do the same in the space of symmetric matrices too.

Comment: Is the conversion using $U$ and $V$ equivalent? I can see that it gives a bound on the optimal solution. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Yes, since you minimize the upper bound and every $x\in\mathbb R$ can be expressed as $u-v$ with $u=\max\{x, 0\}$ and $v=\max\{-x, 0\}$.

Comment: Thanks. What are the semidefinite constraints ?

Comment: I would apply semidefinite constraint only to $Q$. You could express $U\ge 0$ (component wise) with a semidefinite constraint, by replacing $U$ with $\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{svec}(U))$. However, this would lead to unnecessarily large matrices. Just regard $U$ as the vector $\operatorname{svec}(U)$. The same applies to $V$.